# shell - Compare a string to a variable(string or number)

Tags: shell, string-comparison

I want to find out if the string variable is empty or not. I do this by comparing the variable to a literal empty string (`""`).

Here is my code:

```
var=$1

if [$var == ""]; then
    echo "\$var is $var"
fi
```

It gives me this error when `$1` is `""` (No command line argument(s)):

```
./script.sh: line 5: [: ==: unary operator expected
```

When `$1` has a value, it works fine.

I've tried the following things and they still have given me an error:

1. Changing `==` to `-eq`.
2. Surrounding `$var` with `""`.
3. Putting a `space` inside `""` to make it `" "`.
4. Different combinations of 1-3

I want to be able to compare a string variable (empty or not) with `""`.

Comment: Which shell are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always have a space after the opening bracket (`[`), because it's a command name.

The way to do it closest to your own: `if [ "$var" = "" ]; then...`

Another way to do it (`-n` predicate which test for non-emptiness): `if [ -n "$var" ]; then...`

Double quotes around `$var` are required.

Comment: To keep the same sense of the original test you'd want to use `[ -z "$var" ]` (-z: true if the argument is a zero-length string)